# OpenAL offset race condition

Tags: ios, race-condition, openal

I'm using OpenAL on iOS and seem to be getting some kind of race condition where rapid alternating calls to get and set AL_BYTE_OFFSET end up resetting the value to 0. This is all done while the audio source is playing.

```
+ (void) seekTrackSeconds:(float)bytesDelta
{
  ALint position;
  alGetSourcei(sourcesArr[targetSourceIdx], AL_BYTE_OFFSET, &position);

  NSLog(@"byte pos read: %d", position);

  alSourcei(sourcesArr[targetSourceIdx], AL_BYTE_OFFSET, position + bytesDelta);
}
```

After the first 3 calls (always 3...kinda weird), the output of byte pos read resets to 0. I feel like there's a race condition with setting / reading that value. I put a sleep for 20ms between the read and write and get a less frequent occurrence of the error. At 200ms sleep, I don't notice it, but that's unacceptable performance.

Anyone experience the same issue? Background is I'm trying to implement a 'scroll to seek' functionality for song playback. As you scroll a virtual jog wheel, the song should fast forward.

Comment: What is `bytesDelta` set to? If it becomes NaN or a similar nasty value, it will seek to 0 (and more generally, why are you representing a byte delta as a float?). Also, I'm not sure, but I don't think seeking to arbitrary bytes is a good idea; if you end up part-way through a multi-byte value it could end strangely.

Comment: @Dave thanks for pointing that out. bytesDelta is variable depending input and it's never NaN (but I should indeed have a check). I was originally setting AL_SEC_OFFSET so the float is an oversight. Been playing around with AL_SEC_OFFSET and same behavior.